# how to post data from dynamically created radio and checkbox fields in React JS

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am creating lot of radio and checkbox fields in a form. I want to post these data to API.
How this can be possible my form code is like this.

```
     My Submit Function is this

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();
        let frmData = new FormData();
        console.log(frmData);
        let BaseURL = 'https://*****/createtaxform.php';
        
    fetch(BaseURL, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(frmData)
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((res) => {
           console.log(res);
            })
          .catch((error) => {
           console.log(error);
          
          });


      } 
     
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                
             {  formsList.map((item, index,temp=0) => {
              
                 /* for checkboxes name with array [] */
                 return(
                    <div className="custom-control custom-control-alternative custom-checkbox mb-3">
                   <input className="custom-control-input"
                      id= {item.id}
                      name= {item.checkBoxfieldName}
                      type="checkbox"
                      value={item.id}/>
                    <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor={item.id}>
                        {item.form_title}
                    </label>
               </div>
               )
             
          })}
           
         <Button type="submit" >Update</Button>
         </Form>
```

I want to post this data via Fetch Function so please help to resolve my problem with thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi Resolved issue to Post serialized data to API
First Install form serialize

```
   npm install form-serialize
```

Then Import

```
   import serialize from 'form-serialize'
```

Then call Onsubmit

```
 onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = e.currentTarget
    const body = serialize(form, {hash: true, empty: true})
    console.log('submitted!', body)
   }
```